# Can you publish a message to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hello I am learning the Java API for AWS but I am confused as how to send a SNS message from the Lambda code in Java (I saw it can be done in JavaScript but what is the Java equivalent?). Thanks in advance for your support

My set up:

[image: My setup]

Here is my snippet:

```
package at.mavila.aws.laplace;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SNSEvent;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

public class LaplaceController implements RequestHandler<Map, String> {

    private static final String SUCCESS = "SUCCESS";
    private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(final Map input, final Context context) {

        final LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

        logger.log("Env variables: " + GSON.toJson(System.getenv()));
        logger.log("Context: " + GSON.toJson(context));
        logger.log("Event: " + GSON.toJson(input));
        logger.log("Event class: " + GSON.toJson(input.getClass().getName()));

        //Perform calculation


        //Send SNS subscription with result (Email)
        final SNSEvent.SNS sns = new SNSEvent.SNS();
        //... What next?
        //sns.setTopicArn();

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"send a SNS subscription from the Lambda code"* does not make sense, you want to create a subscription or do you want to send a message, you cannot send a subscription.

Comment: hello @luk2302, the subscription is already created and it works, I can receive a test email, yes, I would like to send a message

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorial-publish-message-to-topic.html#publish-message-to-topic-aws-java

Comment: Yes, thanks, I saw that before, but where is declared "snsClient" ? final PublishResult publishResponse = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);

Comment: Looks it is like this, correct me if I am wrong: SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                .build();

Comment: You may not even have to specify a region since you are in a lambda which already lives within a region - if your topic is in the same region.